# Add a transform value without erasing inherit

Tags: css, css-transforms

So I have the following CSS:

```
div {
  transform: translate(10, 10);
}

div.active {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

The problem is that a `div.active` doesn't `translate` and only `scale`s.

Ain't there a **CSS-only** (with [JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010523/add-a-transform-value-to-the-current-transforms-that-are-already-on-the-element) I know I can) way to write something like:

```
div.active {
  transform: inherit scale(1.1);
}
```

?

Is this some kind of CSS3 design issue?

Comment: I guess you could call this a design weakness. Same goes for `background-image`, `box-shadow` etc. A very cheap work around would be to add another child to `div.active` and perform the second  transform on this child element. But is rather ugly, not always possible and requires changes to the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}
div.active {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px) scale(1.1);
}
div.active2 {
  transform: scale(1.1) translate(10px, 10px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="active"></div>
```

The transform property of your `active` class is overwriting the original value.

You would have to state **both** in your active class.

**Note**: `translate` values require units

```
div {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}

div.active {
  transform: translate(10px, 10px) scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Which means that in the definition of `div.active`, I need to know about the `div` transform. If I don't, there is no other solution?

Comment: Some kind of software could add this missing features to CSS, just like we do with Javascript and Babel.

Comment: This is a big gap in the CSS spec.  Now I cannot add another `transform` to an element on top of what I framework provided.

Comment: You can use CSS variables though, and those can be used inside a CSS transform. So you can extend a CSS transform down the inheritance chain:
`
--extra-transform: "";

.above-myclass-1 {
  --extra-transform: var(--extra-transform) scale(1.2);
}

.myclass-1 {
  transform: var(--extra-transform) rotate(10deg);
}
````