# Update the rotate() property within a transform attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, transform

How do I only update the `rotate(19deg)` property within the transform attribute without affecting the `translate3d()`, `translate()` properties?

Below is my divs property. I would like to manipulate just the rotate() property using JavaScript so the other properties are left as they are.

```
transform: translate3d(782px, 312px, 0px) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(19deg) translate(0px, 0px);
```

So after updating using JavaScript, my divs transform property will look like this:

```
transform: translate3d(782px, 312px, 0px) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px);
```

Notice the `rotate(0deg)`

Thanks guys

Comment: You would need to do something like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010523/add-a-transform-value-to-the-current-transforms-that-are-already-on-the-element/30010571#30010571). Basically extract the current transform value, check with regex and replace as appropriate.

Comment: When would this change occur, on click? Or?

Comment: @Harry yes I did think of this but was hoping for a much simpler way!

Comment: @BrunoKos yes a click event

Comment: @CecilTheodore: I don't think there is any simpler way. In fact if the original transform is set through CSS (and we have to use `getComputedStyle` for getting the original transform value), it gets more trickier because it would return a matrix equivalent that would need reconstruction.

Comment: @Harry there is a simpler way of getting the transform value - jqueryObject.context.style.transform

Answer (score 0):

If your idea is to leave the element in 0deg position with no option to return back to 19deg via click, you could go with:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="rotateme">
  <p class="clickme">Click Me</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#rotateme {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(382px, 112px, 0px) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(19deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(382px, 112px, 0px) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(19deg) translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(382px, 112px, 0px) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(19deg) translate(0px, 0px);
}

.clickme {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
  $("#rotateme").css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(382px, 112px, 0px) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px)");
  $("#rotateme").css("transform", "translate3d(382px, 112px, 0px) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px)");
  $("#rotateme").css("-ms-transform", "translate3d(382px, 112px, 0px) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px)");
});
```

I did not use the exact values you asked as it would push the box below the visible area (at least with my current Codepen set up), but you can see which one require change. Also, I'm using transition for smooth rotation and prefixes so it would work on all modern browsers.

Codepen example is available [here](http://codepen.io/bbirdme/pen/dMGzvw).

Comment: Thanks for attempting, but the issue with this implementation is it does not account for the fact the translate, translate properties will always be changing.

Comment: You mean on click, it will return back to original state?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear initially. but the translate3d(782px, 312px, 0px) translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) can all change. So I will be interacting with a div that will not have static translate3d() and transform() values

Comment: but how will you change those values then?

Comment: the div has the ability to be rotated using an external source thus changing the translate3d() and transform properties