# How can I get transform and add scale?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform, scale

I have an object which already has some kind of transform applied (but not scaling) with JavaScript. Mainly these:
`(translate(69.8671px, 258.873px) translateZ(9999px) rotate(0deg);`

What I would like to do is to apply scale to this as well.

I can read object transform with this:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle($(this)[0]);
var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.transform);
```

Is there a way I could now apply scale to this already existing transforms? I want to do this on mouseenter, mouseleave so I need to remove the scale well later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010523/add-a-transform-value-to-the-current-transforms-that-are-already-on-the-element

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add multiple values applied one after another. The values must be separated by space. [W3docs](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css.html)

You can get the computed style outside of your callback function then run the callback and check the `event.type`, if ***mouseenter*** add the transform to your inline style and *concatenate* your ***scale*** value using the following code:

```js
e.target.style.transform = `${transform} scale(1.5)`
```

If ***mouseout***, set it back to the original ***transform*** variable.

### Pure JavaScript:

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box')

const transform = getComputedStyle(box).getPropertyValue('transform')

function scale(e) {
  e.type === 'mouseenter' ?
    e.target.style.transform = `${transform} scale(1.5)` : 
    e.target.style.transform = `${transform}`
}

box.addEventListener('mouseenter', scale)
box.addEventListener('mouseout', scale)
```

```css
:root {
  --width: 200px;
}

.box {
  width: var(--width);
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(calc(50vw - calc(var(--width)/2))); 
  transition: transform ease-in-out 1s;
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

### jQuery equivalent:

```js
const $box = $('.box')

const transform = $box.css('transform')

function scale(e) {
  e.type === 'mouseenter' ?
    $(this).css('transform', `${transform} scale(1.5)`) : 
    $(this).css('transform', transform)
}

$box.on('mouseenter', scale)
$box.on('mouseout', scale)
```

```css
:root {
  --width: 200px;
}

.box {
  width: var(--width);
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(calc(50vw - calc(var(--width)/2))); 
  transition: transform ease-in-out 1s;
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you want to do this by hand, because you have some cascading transformations before hand. In that case, initialize a DOMMatrix by hand:

```js
let mtrx =new DOMMatrix("matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 69.8671, 258.873, 9999, 1)"
    .replace(/matrix3d\s*\(|\)/gi,"")
    .split(",")
    .map(d => +d))
```

this will give you 4 x 4 transformation matrix:

```
|m11  .  . .
|m21 m22 . .
|m31 m32 . .
|m41  .  . .
```

in a 2d matrix, scaleX is `a` and scaleY is `d`, likewise in 3d matrix scaleX is `m11` and scaleY is `m22`. So if you want to increase scale by 2, you can:

```js
mtrx.m11 *= 2 //scaleX
mtrx.m22 *= 2 //scaleY
mtrx.m33 *= 2 //scaleZ
```

you can also call built in `scale3dSelf`:

```js
mtrx.scale3dSelf(3)
```

then compile the object back to string and set it as transform:

```js
el.style.transform = mtrx.toString()
```

<sup>Note:
Remember that if you multiply like this, your translates are not scaled, if you also want to scale the translates, then you need to multiply 4th col (mX4) as well.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can get and set css property of an element using css() method in jQuery.
Here is documentation link: https://api.jquery.com/css/

here is my example:

```js
let cssVal = null;

      yourMouseEnterFunction = function () {
        // setting of box element's css property (background-color) to blue
        $(".box").css("background-color", "blue");
        // setting of box element's css property (transform) to rotate(20deg)
        $(".box").css("transform", "rotate(20deg)");
        cssVal = getCssVal(".box", "transform");
        $("#result").text(cssVal);
      };

      yourMouseLeaveFunction = function () {
        // setting of box element's css property (background-color) to red
        $(".box").css("background-color", "red");

        // setting of box element's css property (transform) to rotate(0deg)
        $(".box").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)");
        cssVal = getCssVal(".box", "transform");
        $("#result").text(cssVal);
      };

      getCssVal = function (selector, propertyName) {
        return $(selector).css(propertyName);
      };

      $(document).ready(function () {
        // adding eventhandlers
        $(".box").mouseenter(yourMouseEnterFunction);
        $(".box").mouseleave(yourMouseLeaveFunction);

        // getting css property value of height from .box element
        var defaultHeight = getCssVal(".box", "height");
        $("#defaultResult").text(defaultHeight);
      });
```

```css
  .box {
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: plum;
        transform: translate(69.8671px, 258.873px);
        transform: translateZ(9999px);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<label>
Default value of (height) on init: <span id="defaultResult"></span>
</label>
<br />
<label>Css Value of (transform) : <span id="result"></span>
</label>
<div class="box"></div>
```