# Apply two different CSS transforms simultanesouly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transforms, requestanimationframe

I am working on a script to adjust an image using transform left and right based on the cursor position.
There is also some CSS to zoom the image on hover.

```js
// JavaScript source code
var catchX = 0,
    catchY = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    burn = 1 / 28;

function imageWatch() {
    x += (catchX - x) * burn;

    translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    $('.image-area img').css({
        '-webit-transform': translate,
        '-moz-transform': translate,
        'transform': translate
    });

    window.requestAnimationFrame(imageWatch);
}

$(window).on('mousemove click', function (e) {

    var mouseX = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).width() / 2 - e.clientX));
    catchX = (26 * mouseX) / 100;

});

imageWatch();
```

```css
html,body { height:100%}
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
*, *::before, *::after {
  content:"\0020";
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.poster {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden !important
}
 .image-area {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            opacity: .24;
            transition: 2.5s ease;
        }

.image-area {
            opacity: 1;
        }


.image-area > img {
            margin-top: -312px;
            margin-left: -913px;
            width: auto;
            /* height: auto */
            height: 1000px;
            transform: scale(1,1);
            transition:8s all;
        }

.poster:hover .image-area > img {
            transform: scale(1.3,1.3)
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poster">
    <div class="image-area">
         <img class="poster" src="https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/f/fc/Sky_Believe_in_better_logo.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110910152552" alt="Sky" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="poster">
    <div class="image-area">
         <img class="poster" src="https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/f/fc/Sky_Believe_in_better_logo.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110910152552" alt="Sky" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="poster">
    <div class="image-area">
         <img class="poster" src="https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/f/fc/Sky_Believe_in_better_logo.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110910152552" alt="Sky" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS is using the transform property, and so is my CSS to make it zoom on hover. I think this is the problem.

If you remove the transform from the CSS, the script works fine, but I need the `transition:8s all` for the image to zoom on hover, as well as to align it with the cursor.

This [S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css) informed me that you can have two transform properties but they must be on one line. How do I do that with my Javascript?

---

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apdajj4L/5/)

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769800/how-to-set-a-single-value-of-transform-while-leaving-the-other-values

Comment: You're just going to have to parse and construct the string yourself. Or lean how to do `matrix` transforms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) is a single property, so you can't target from CSS for only part of it, e.g, you cannot set different CSS `transition-duration` for two [transform-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function) applied in the same `transform` property.

You could write everything through js, updating yourself both transform-functions values over time, but that would be a lot of work, for a potentially non-hardware accelerated result, while there is a simple workaround.

The easiest solution is to change a little bit your structure so that you apply the `scale` on a wrapper element, and the translate on the inner-one.

This way, both transforms are applied on your inner `<img>`, but they don't conflict each other.

```js
// JavaScript source code
var catchX = 0,
  catchY = 0,
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
  burn = 1 / 28;

function imageWatch() {
  x += (catchX - x) * burn;

  translate = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

  $('.image-area img').css({
    '-webit-transform': translate,
    '-moz-transform': translate,
    'transform': translate
  });

  window.requestAnimationFrame(imageWatch);
}

$(window).on('mousemove click', function(e) {

  var mouseX = Math.max(-100, Math.min(100, $(window).width() / 2 - e.clientX));
  catchX = (26 * mouseX) / 100;

});

imageWatch();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  content: "\0020";
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.poster {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden !important
}

.image-area {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: .24;
  transition: 2.5s ease;
}

.image-area {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-area img {
  margin-top: -312px;
  margin-left: -913px;
  width: auto;
  /* height: auto */
  height: 1000px;
 /* here we can remove the transition */
}


/* scaling on hover is only applied on the parent elmt */

.image-area>.scaler {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  transition: 8s transform;
}

.poster:hover .image-area>.scaler {
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poster">
  <div class="image-area">
    <!-- the scaling wrapper-->
    <div class="scaler">
      <img class="poster" src="https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/f/fc/Sky_Believe_in_better_logo.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110910152552" alt="Sky" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="poster">
  <div class="image-area">
    <!-- the scaling wrapper-->
    <div class="scaler">
      <img class="poster" src="https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/f/fc/Sky_Believe_in_better_logo.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110910152552" alt="Sky" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="poster">
  <div class="image-area">
    <!-- the scaling wrapper-->
    <div class="scaler">
      <img class="poster" src="https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/f/fc/Sky_Believe_in_better_logo.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110910152552" alt="Sky" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```