# change values of transform: translate(-13px, 0px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg) separately

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I want to make 2 spans work like a mirror image , when i move one second will have to move in opposite direction

First Span

```
<span style="transform: translate(-13px, 0px) scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);">
<img src="./ImageEditor Demo_files/ImageRight.png" style="width: 750px; height: 750px;">
</span>
```

Second Span

```
<span style="transform: translate(13px, 0px) scale(-1, -1) rotate(-0deg);">
<img src="./ImageEditor Demo_files/ImageLeft.png" style="width: 750px; height: 750px;">
</span>
```

logic I am using

```
var observer1 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
      var transform1 = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[3].style.transform;
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.transform = transform1
      
  });    
});

var target = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

It trigger when css of first changes & it change css of 2nd span same as first one but i want it to like if rotate for first is 10deg then for 2nd it should be -10deg, same for translate and scale

Please have a look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a single value of transform while leaving the other values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769800/how-to-set-a-single-value-of-transform-while-leaving-the-other-values)

Comment: use CSS variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using split

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  
  arrsplit = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.transform.split(/[\(,)px]+/);
  replace = arrsplit[7].replace('deg','')
  mirror= arrsplit[0]+"("+parseFloat(arrsplit[1])*-1+"px"+", "+parseFloat(arrsplit[2])*1+"px"+")"
  +arrsplit[3]+"("+parseFloat(arrsplit[4])*1+", "+parseFloat(arrsplit[5])*1+")"+
  arrsplit[6]+"("+parseFloat(replace)*-1+"deg"+")";

  mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('span')[3].style.transform = mirror
  console.log('style changed!');
}

 var observer1 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  
  arrsplit = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[3].style.transform.split(/[\(,)px]+/);
  replace = arrsplit[7].replace('deg','')
  mirror= arrsplit[0]+"("+parseFloat(arrsplit[1])*-1+"px"+", "+parseFloat(arrsplit[2])*1+"px"+")"
  +arrsplit[3]+"("+parseFloat(arrsplit[4])*1+", "+parseFloat(arrsplit[5])*1+")"+
  arrsplit[6]+"("+parseFloat(replace)*-1+"deg"+")";
  
  mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
  var transform1 = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[3].style.transform;
  document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.transform = mirror
  
  });    
  });
  
  var target = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
  var target2 = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[3];
  observer1.observe(target2, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
  observer.observe(target, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **[regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)** to extract all the number values from the transform-string and then put them back in after you've inverted/mirrored them:

```js
[mirror].style.transform = [source].style.transform.replace(/[-?\.?\d]+/g,function(match){return -1*Number(match);});
```

- This regex pattern (`/.../g`) basically looks for all (`g`) numbers (`\d+`) in the provided string, with optional minus sign (`-?`) and/or decimal point (`\.?`).
  See **https://regexr.com/57knk** for a detailed explanation on how this pattern works.
- See **[string.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** and **[string.replace() with function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)** for information on how the rest of the `replace` function works.

In the **live snippet** below I changed a few other things as well, to make your code more flexible, I'll comment on those changes after the snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('transform').onclick = function(){document.getElementsByClassName('elem source')[0].style.transform = this.previousElementSibling.value;};
/*ONLY FOR DEMO*/

var elemMirror = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(mutation.target.className.replace('source','mirror'))[0].style.transform = mutation.target.style.transform.replace(/[-?\.?\d]+/g,function(match){return -1*Number(match);});
  });
});
elemMirror.observe(document.getElementsByClassName('elem source')[0], {attributes:true, attributeFilter:['style']});
```

```css
form {width:100%; margin-bottom:30px;}
form span {font-weight:bold;}
form input {margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}
form input[type=text] {width:calc(100% - 50px); font-family:monospace;}
form input[type=button] {width:50px;}
/*ONLY FOR DEMO*/

.elem {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0px,0px) scale(1,1) rotate(0deg);
}
.elem img {width:79px; height:79px;}
```

```html
<form>
  <span>Transform the first, mirror the second:</span><br />
  <input type="text" value="translate(0px,0px) scale(1,1) rotate(0deg)" /><input type="button" id="transform" value="apply" />
</form>
<!--ONLY FOR DEMO-->

<div class="elem source"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiZzP.png"></div>
<div class="elem mirror"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiZzP.png"></div>
```

***jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hk2gbuj6/4/***

- Everything above the `ONLY FOR DEMO` comments is, as stated, only for demonstration purposes so you can play around with it.
- I changed your `span` to `div`, because I couldn't get `transform` to work on a `span`.
- I gave the first `div` `class="elem source"`, and the second `div` `class="elem mirror"`.
  The class `elem` can be whatever your want it to be, just make sure that the *source*  and *mirror* element both have the same class.
  Then, make sure the original/*source* element has class `source`, and the element that is supposed to *mirror* that original/source element, has class `mirror`. These two classes will be used in the *MutationObserver* function to refer to the two elements in a variable way.
- Now, inside `MutationObserver()`, instead of hard-coding the *source* and *mirror* elements into the function (your `('span')[0]` and `('span')[3]`), I refer to them in a variable manner:

  1. I use `mutation.target` to refer to the *source* element.
  2. I use `mutation.target.className.replace('source','mirror')` to refer to the *mirror* element.
  3. So now you only have to change the `target` when you call [`MutationObserver.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe):
     `elemMirror.observe(document.getElementsByClassName('elem source')[0], {...});`

---

### Choose which transform-values to mirror:

If you don't want to mirror all transform-values, but only a selected few, change this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName(mutation.target.className.replace('source','mirror'))[0].style.transform = mutation.target.style.transform.replace(/[-?\.?\d]+/g,function(match){return -1*Number(match);});
```

to this:

```js
var mirrorValues = ['translate','rotate']; //transform-values to mirror
var transform = mutation.target.style.transform.split(') ');
transform.forEach(function(item,index) {
  if (mirrorValues.indexOf(item.substring(0,item.indexOf('('))) != -1) {
    transform[index] = item.replace(/[-?\.?\d]+/g,function(match){return -1*Number(match);});
  }
});
document.getElementsByClassName(mutation.target.className.replace('source','mirror'))[0].style.transform = transform.join(') ');
```

```js
document.getElementById('transform').onclick = function(){document.getElementsByClassName('elem source')[0].style.transform = this.previousElementSibling.value;};
/*ONLY FOR DEMO*/

var elemMirror = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    var mirrorValues = document.getElementById('mirrorValues').value.split(',');
    var transform = mutation.target.style.transform.split(') ');
    transform.forEach(function(item,index) {
      if (mirrorValues.indexOf(item.substring(0,item.indexOf('('))) != -1) {
        transform[index] = item.replace(/[-?\.?\d]+/g,function(match){return -1*Number(match);});
      }
    });
    document.getElementsByClassName(mutation.target.className.replace('source','mirror'))[0].style.transform = transform.join(') ');
  });
});
elemMirror.observe(document.getElementsByClassName('elem source')[0], {attributes:true, attributeFilter:['style']});
```

```css
form {width:100%; margin-bottom:20px;}
form span {font-weight:bold;}
form input {margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}
form input[type=text] {width:calc(100% - 50px); font-family:monospace;}
form input[type=button] {width:50px;}
/*ONLY FOR DEMO*/

.elem {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0px,0px) scale(1,1) rotate(0deg);
}
.elem img {width:79px; height:79px;}
```

```html
<form>
  <span>Transform-values to mirror (separate by comma):</span><br />
  <input type="text" id="mirrorValues" value="translate,scale,rotate" /><br />
  <span>Transform the first, mirror the second:</span><br />
  <input type="text" value="translate(0px,0px) scale(1,1) rotate(0deg)" /><input type="button" id="transform" value="apply" />
</form>
<!--ONLY FOR DEMO-->

<div class="elem source"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiZzP.png"></div>
<div class="elem mirror"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiZzP.png"></div>
```

***jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hk2gbuj6/5/***

- `var mirrorValues = ['translate','rotate'];` creates an array with all the transform-values to mirror.
  `var mirrorValues = document.getElementById('mirrorValues').value.split(',');` is used in the snippet to create an array from the input-field-text.
- `var transform = mutation.target.style.transform.split(') ');` creates an array from the *source* element's transform-property, in which all the individual values are split up as separate array-values.
- `transform.forEach(function(item,index) {...});` then iterates over all the separate values, and
  `if (mirrorValues.indexOf(item.substring(0,item.indexOf('('))) != -1) {...}` checks whether the value is in the `mirrorValues`-array.
- If it is, `transform[index] = item.replace(/[-?\.?\d]+/g, ...);` will invert/mirror the value.
- Finally, `[mirror].style.transform = transform.join(') ');` will put all the separate array-values together again into one single 'transform' string.

See **[array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**, **[string.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)**, **[string.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**, **[string.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** and **[array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** for more information on all the operations I'm using.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer it is really working , but i manage to do it below is how i managed to make it work